# Add a thirty-second note in MIDI using java

Tags: java, midi

I'm trying to create a MIDI file using java and I'm struggling to make the code add a thirty-second note (after adding it to the sequence and generating the MIDI file, it is empty). Thanks for your help !

EDIT : Here's the code (this one generates a MIDI file with a sixteenth-note)

EDIT2 : The problem was with my midi player actually. Thanks to @Maxim for pointing that out

```
Sequence s = null;

    try {
        s = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 480);
    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Track t = s.createTrack();

    ShortMessage sm = new ShortMessage();

    //instru
    sm.setMessage(ShortMessage.PROGRAM_CHANGE, 0, 25, 0); //9 ==> is the channel 10.
    t.add(new MidiEvent(sm, 0));


    t.add(createNoteOnEvent(75, 0));
    t.add(createNoteOffEvent(75, 120));

    File outputFile = new File("C:\\test.mid");

    MidiSystem.write(s, 0, outputFile);


  private static MidiEvent createNoteOnEvent(int nKey, long lTick)
    {
    return createNoteEvent(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON,
        nKey,
        64,
        lTick);
}



private static MidiEvent createNoteOffEvent(int nKey, long lTick)
{
    return createNoteEvent(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF,
        nKey,
        0,
        lTick);
}

private static MidiEvent createNoteEvent(int nCommand,
                                         int nKey,
                                         int nVelocity,
                                         long lTick)
{
    ShortMessage    message = new ShortMessage();
    try
    {
        message.setMessage(nCommand,
            0,  // always on channel 1
            nKey,
            nVelocity);
    }
    catch (InvalidMidiDataException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    MidiEvent   event = new MidiEvent(message,
        lTick);
    return event;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a midi note of any duration to the sequence and get a non-empty midi file?  Please show the code you have tried that fails.

Comment: @geneSummons I edited the post. If instead of `t.add(createNoteOffEvent(75, 120));` I put `t.add(createNoteOffEvent(75, 60));` to make the note shorter, the bug (if it is one) happens

Comment: @HamzaAlhyar Try to set the number of pulses per quarter note, for example, to 960 instead 480. Then length of a thirty-second note will be 120. And one more question: what do you mean file is empty? After reading your output file it contains no tracks or note on/off messages?

Comment: @Maxim I already tried what you wrote, didn't work. And what I mean is that the tempo is set, the instrument aswell but there isn't any note to be played

Comment: Can you please give me a file that is not played, so I can find out what's wrong with it?

Comment: @Maxim there you go (I generated this one with the parameters you wrote) : https://files.fm/f/pfhb4vtb

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your file. All events are presented in it. Also it is playable by JetAudio for example. So it is definetely the problem with your audio player rather than with Java MIDI API.

Comment: @Maxim omg didn't even try with another midi player, thanks so much !